# Ejercicio sencillo para entender la utilidad de las funciones anónimas

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy estudiando las funciones anónimas en javascript y la verdad es que de momento no le veo el sentido. De momento me parece que puedes hacer lo mismo sin ellas...yo me pregunto ¿qué problema solucionan? ¿Por qué iba a querer tener en mi programa funciones sin nombre? Por otra parte, así de primeras, me suena como un despropósito ya que me imagino que si yo tengo varias funciones anónimas en un .js a la hora de ejecutarlo, si tengo un error en alguna de estas funciones anónimas cómo voy a saber cuál de todas es, ya que no tienen nombre.
**Así que creo que lo ideal para entenderlas sería encontrar, al menos, un caso de uso en el que comparativamente, con respecto a las funciones que tienen nombre se viera la ventaja de usar funciones anónimas.**
Se agradecen respuestas que no hagan referencias a varios conceptos tipo "[Callbacks, código asíncrono y funciones anónimas en Javascript](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2017/10/16/callbacks-codigo-asincrono-funciones-anonimas-en-javascript/)", que de momento con un concepto ya tengo bastante.

Comment: no te imaginas cuantas veces usas funciones anonimas, un tipico ejemplo es el then de una promesa, crear una unica funcion para ese then o lo escribo alli? usando los setTimeOut o setInterval reciben otra funcion(callbacks) a algo tan pequeño te imaginas programar todo eso de una manera un poco mas estructurada seria mas engorroso aun

Comment: Ok, me dices que se utiliza muchísimo y te agradezco tu aportación pero creo que lo que me ayudaría a entenderlo de verás en ver de tener una nube difusa de conceptos, que es lo que me pasa ahora, es ver un ejemplo comparativo de código para hacer algo con funciones anónimas y lo mismo sin ellas. A lo mejor la respuesta que busco no tiene sentido pero como aún no lo entiendo...

Comment: te invito al [chat] y cerrar esta pregunta una vez que te quede claro